# Slow file sharing speed over LAN

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, file-transfer, throughput

I have two ASUS UL80 laptops and trying to copy files from one to another. I also have a Linksys router with WiFI on.

The speed of a file transfer via router + LAN cable (or only the LAN cable) is about 600KB/s.
I tried to turn off firewalls on both PC's, but it increases the speed by only 100KB/s.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do either of the PC's have wireless? If so, wireless N? Did you mean ("or only the LAN cable") that you also tried a direct cable between the computers?

Comment: Thank you, didn't think about this. The files were transferred by wi-fi only, turning it off helped  a lot! do yo know how to set priority to the cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the interface metric to a lower number on the wired connection than the wireless (I think it's on 'advanced' under IPv4 settings) then Windows should prioritise the wired connection. You will of course need to disable automatic metric on both adapters.